# Getting 'Error ' message when I run my for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

So I have a matrix model I am running, and when the model is told to stop I get a message that says 'Error:'

Now the model is running fine, it is stopping it when it is supposed to etc. But this means I can't run it more than once in a loop, which isn't ideal. So I was wondering if there was a way to get this Error message to stop occurring, or to bypass it.

Dummy code below:

```
n.steps <- 100
x <- array(0,c(85,n.steps)) 
mnalph<-50

x[12,]<-2
x[24,]<-2
x[40,]<-3
x[50,]<-1
x[70,]<-2
x[85,] <- 1  

k<-0

for (i in 2:n.steps){
  k<-k+1

  a<-sample(c(replicate(1000, 
                        sample(c(1,0), prob=c(0.75, 0.25), size = 1))),1)
  mat[85,85] <- a
  currclass <- replacementclass <- round(rnorm(1, mean = mnalph, sd = 11))
  if (a == 0) {

    d <- sample(1:100, 1)
    if (d > 60) {
      x[85,k]<-0
      stop()

    } else {

      while(a == 0) {
        while (a == 0) {
          if (x[currclass, k] > 1) {

            x[currclass, k] <- x[currclass, k] - 1
            a <- 1
            x[85,k]<-a

          } else {

            nonzeroes<-which(x[0:84,k]>0) 
            distances<-abs(nonzeroes - currclass) 
            minlocs<-nonzeroes[which(distances==min(distances))] 
            replacementclass<-minlocs
            if(x[replacementclass, k]>=1){
              x[replacementclass, k]<- x[replacementclass, k] - 1}
            else {
              x[replacementclass, k]<- 0}
            a <- 1
            x[85,k]<-a

            if (all(x[11:84, k] == 0)) {
              stop()
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The error that I get is `Error in k.vec[i] <- k : object 'k.vec' not found`  and indeed your code does not have anything called  k.vec.   Did you want to initialize it - maybe with `k.vec=NULL`.    BTW  it looks like you also refer to other variables,  a.vec and mat,  that are never created.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`stop()` always returns [an error message](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.2/topics/stop):

> stop stops execution of the current expression and executes an error action.

If you want to break out of the loop, replace it with `break`.

See [`?Control`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.2/topics/Control) for details.

Your example does not run (some object definitions are missing for `k.vec` and `a.vec`, for instance), but I suspect this simple replacement will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for this - stupidly forgot to remove that, it was just for diagnostic purposes, have done so now.

Comment: Well thankyou I thought it was helpful. Much better to say why code isn't working than just giving the answer so thanks and ta for pointing out the dummy code wasn't working.

Comment: The `stop()` function also takes in arguments to produce an error message. This may be a useful way to diagnose whether that _specific_ line is producing the error. (e.g. `stop("all(x[11:84, k] == 0) condition is met.")`)